# Connect docker container to database in host's local network

Tags: networking, docker, proxy, psql, docker-network

I am running a docker container containing a node server that needs to connect to a psql db in a local network, with a private ip address, I'll show my current configuration:

[image]

The container exposes the 3000 port to connect to the node server

But when I run it I get a connection refused error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.9.0.0:5432
```

I know that the db is accepting connections from other ips in the network since this is not the only app using this db server.

What is the docker way to achieve this?

I am running:
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
OS: Win10 but this also needs to work on MacOS

Thank you!

Comment: Can you ping `10.9.0.0` in your docker container?

Comment: Try ping db host from docker host if it's ok try ping from a docker container if it's ok try psql in a testing container.

Comment: ICMP is being rejected in 10.9.0.0, I am able to connect ok with other dbs inside containers (like a psql container) @BillCheng

Comment: is the db accessible from Docker host? If so, it should be accessible from container.

Comment: it is, the problem solved after fixing the issues with the security groups

Comment: @JesusGomez How did you do the setup ? I am trying to setup datasource in jboss wildfly. The database is on the LAN to which host machine is connected to same as what you have given in your image. I tried running the jboss wilddfly container --network=host option but still this does not ping to any of the machines connected on host LAN.